# android sdk 3 emulator fail to launch on windows 7 32bit

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator

I started android developmental by installing android sdk and eclipse and then ADT plug in on windows 7 32bit machine 4G Ram and 2.93GHz processor . I was able to setup an AVD and launch it. Then after trying to launch my first app  the emulator always hangs and the app does not launch. I found that there might be problem with my installation and they suggested to re-install a fresh copy which I did. It worked fine then and I was able to launch my app on emulator. Next day when I started my eclipse I'm facing the same problem again, I would very much appreciate any help or ideas.
Thanks,

**update** 
I have tried to create another AVD with different target and it hangs for a while before creating the new AVD. This did not solve the problem the new AVD also keeps hanging with not responding sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reinstalling the Android SDK and Eclipse plugin. I was hoping for a better solution but did not find any.